# Why doesn't mousePress do anything?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, key-bindings

I am new to Java and I'm trying to make an auto clicker. It works like this. when you click a button, the application starts clicking (also works when you press s), and when you press "w" the application stops clicking. My main issue currently is I can't manage to make my application click :V. (I also have a "main.java" for startup) Here's my code vvvvvvv

```
    package copy;

import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;





import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game 
implements ActionListener{

    JFrame frame;
    JLabel label;
    JButton button;
    Action ON;
    Action OFF;
    private static Robot bot;
    public static boolean status = false;
    
    Game(){
        ON = new statusON();
        OFF = new statusOFF();
        
        frame = new JFrame("Bullet Chicken Clicker");
        label = new JLabel();
        button = new JButton("turn on?");
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setLocation(600, 150);
        frame.setVisible(true); 
        frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.add(button); 
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "OFF");
        label.getActionMap().put("OFF", OFF);
        
        

        
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "upAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("upAction", ON);
        label.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), "downAction");
        label.getActionMap().put("downAction", OFF);
        
        button.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(40, 40));
        button.setOpaque(true);
        button.setForeground(Color.BLACK);   
        button.setBounds(125, 150, 150, 30);
        button.setVisible(true);
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setFocusable(false);
    }
    
    private void clicky() {
        while (status == true);
            bot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            bot.delay(300);
            bot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            bot.delay(300);
    }
    public static void robot() {
        try {
            bot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public class statusON extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            status = true;
            System.out.print(status);
        }       
    }
    public class statusOFF extends AbstractAction{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            status = false;
            System.out.print(status);
        }       
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        status = true;
        System.out.print(status);
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Please do not repost questions. Stack Overflow is a Q&A site, not a message board. Reposting only serves to clutter the site, which actually makes it harder for you and others to find answers. You should either delete the old question or this one, since they are materially identical.

Comment: ok I will try not to

Comment: Include the "Swing" tag if you want Swing developers to notice your question.

Comment: *I just can't manage to get my robot to click at all. Any advice?* - I have no idea what you expect to happen. If you want the Robot to click a component on your frame, then you need to set the location of the Robot to the location of your component on the frame. I think you can use the `getLocationOnScreen()` method.  Don't use looping code for a simple test. The delay between the pressed/released may need to be shorter Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. You just need a frame. However, I recommend you don't use the Robot, There are generally better alternatives.

Comment: ok forget about everything I've said. I finally got the robot to click but keybindings still do not work. when the robot starts clicking, non of the key binds work anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My main issue currently is I can't manage to make my application click :V.

Well, you don't assign a key binding to the "V" key. You define the binding for "W" twice.

Having said that your code is still incorrect and will cause you problems in the future:

1. you are adding two components to the BorderLayout.CENTER
2. components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible
3. you are using the wrong InputMap

From the tutorial given to you in your last question there are 3 InputMaps. The default InputMap will only work when the component has focus. In your incorrect example is just happens that the label does have focus. However, if you add more components it will likely not retain focus.

In the case of a game the easiest way to make sure you game responds to the `KeyStroke` is to bind the `KeyStroke` to the `InputMap` of the `JRootPane` of the frame. Then it doesn't matter which component on the frame has focus, the Action will be invoked.

So your code should be something like:

```
JRootPane rootPane = frame.getRootPane();
InputMap im = rootPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('v'), "OFF");
rootPane.getActionMap().put("OFF", OFF);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('w'), "upAction");
rootPane.getActionMap().put("upAction", ON);
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('s'), "downAction");
rootPane.getActionMap().put("downAction", OFF);
```

There is no need for the JLabel.

Comment: thanks I got it to work now. I just can't manage to get my robot to click at all. Any advice?